# SQLで複数列のデータを一つにまとめるViewを作りたい

Tags: sql

| Name | TEL1 | TEL2 | TEL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tarou | 000-0000-0000 | 111-1111-1111 | 222-2222-2222 |
| Hanako | 333-3333-3333 | 444-4444-4444 | NULL |

という一つのテーブルに同じ項目を複数持っているようなものをばらして

| Name | TEL |
| --- | --- |
| Tarou | 000-0000-0000 |
| Tarou | 111-1111-1111 |
| Tarou | 222-2222-2222 |
| Hanako | 333-3333-3333 |
| Hanako | 444-4444-4444 |

という感じのViewを作りたいです。
どのようなSQL文を書けばいいでしょうか。

Comment: 質問はあくまで質問の体裁を保ってください。確認結果は役にたった回答に対してコメントをつけるか、新しい回答として投稿すべきです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name, TEL1 と Name, TEL2 と　Name, TEL3 との select 文をそれぞれ
union all して、 Name で order by すればいいのではなｋでしょうか。

Comment: sqlite3で試してみました。

create table test(name text,tel1 text,tel2 text,tel3 text);
insert into test values('Tarou','000-0000-0000','111-1111-1111','222-2222-2222');
insert into test values('Hanako','333-3333-3333','444-4444-4444',null);

select name,tel from (select name,tel1 as tel from test union all select name,tel2 as tel from test union all select name,tel3 as tel from test) where tel is not null order by name;

確かに望んでいた結果になりました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

既に正攻法で解決済みですが、別解としてOracle 11g R1以降ならば`Unpivot`構文で横行を縦列に変換できます。
参考資料: [Oracle 11g R1新機能のPivotとUnPivot](https://codezine.jp/article/detail/4985?p=4)

```
select NAME, TEL
from TEST
unpivot include nulls (TEL for COL_NAME IN (TEL1, TEL2, TEL3))
```

PostgreSQLなど`cross join`できる環境であれば交差結合で結合できます。
下記の`cross join unnest`と`cross join lateral`は同一の結果になります。
参考資料: [SQL で縦横変換まとめ（pivot と unpivot）](https://qiita.com/k24d/items/79bc4828c918dfeeac34)、[MySQL - How to unpivot columns to rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64404865)

```
SELECT A.NAME,
X.TEL
FROM MY_ADDRS A
cross join unnest (
array[TEL1, TEL2, TEL3]
) as X(TEL)
/*
cross join lateral (
select TEL1
union all select TEL2
union all select TEL3
) as X(TEL)
*/
```

なお、SQL Serverにも`Unpivot`構文が用意されていますが、`include nulls`に該当するオプションが見つかりませんでした。
代用として`cross apply`構文が利用できるようです。
参考資料: [Include NULL values in unpivot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42642951)、[How to unpivot columns using CROSS APPLY in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48654400)